# Electron: electron-builder unable to load preload script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an issue with Electron unable to load BrowserWindow preload script. With the next error line:

> Unable to load preload script:
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\myApp\resources\app.asar\electron\preload.js

Here are the versions I use: `"electron": "^11.0.1"`, `"electron-builder": "^22.3.6"`. Also here is the script I launch the new window:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1400,
  height: 900,
  frame: false,
  title: title.name,
  webPreferences: {
    frame: false,
    webviewTag: true,
    nodeIntegration: true,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
    preload: path.join(`${__dirname}/electron`, 'preload.js'),
  },
});
```

The weird part about this is that I have another Electron app with an older Electron version and I have no issues whatsoever, versions: `"electron": "^8.2.3"` & `"electron-builder": "^22.5.1"`.

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1400,
  height: 900,
  frame: false,
  title: title.name,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(`${__dirname}/electron`, 'preload.js'),
    nodeIntegration: true,
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
    webviewTag: true,
  },
});
```

The only differences I have is `nodeIntegrationInWorker` and `enableRemoteModule`. Are any of these properties not allowed to work together? Or is this the Electron version deprecating some of them? How can I fix the error

Comment: If you use `path.join` why do you manually join is the first two parts? Wouldn't you want to get the benefit for all parts of the path? `path.join(__dirname, 'electron', 'preload.js')`

Comment: If you turn off asar does it work? Also, if you take off `nodeIntegrationInWorker` and `enableRemoteModule` does it work?

Comment: just trying to exclude the common errors: do you have any build steps  (like webpack) before building with electron-builder? do you have a files array in the electron-builder config and the preload script may be missing there?